# non linear regression with random effect and lsoda

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations, non-linear-regression, nlme

I am facing a problem I do not manage to solve. I would like to use `nlme` or `nlmODE` to perform a non linear regression with random effect using as a model the solution of a second order differential equation with fixed coefficients (a damped oscillator).

I manage to use `nlme` with simple models, but it seems that the use of `deSolve` to generate the solution of the differential equation causes a problem. Below an example, and the problems I face.

## The data and functions

Here is the function to generate the solution of the differential equation using `deSolve`:

```
library(deSolve)
ODE2_nls <- function(t, y, parms) {
  S1 <- y[1]
  dS1 <- y[2]
  dS2 <- dS1
  dS1 <- - parms["esp2omega"]*dS1  - parms["omega2"]*S1 + parms["omega2"]*parms["yeq"]
  res <- c(dS2,dS1)
  list(res)}

solution_analy_ODE2 = function(omega2,esp2omega,time,y0,v0,yeq){
  parms  <- c(esp2omega = esp2omega,
              omega2 = omega2,
              yeq = yeq)
  xstart = c(S1 =  y0, dS1 = v0)
  out <-  lsoda(xstart, time, ODE2_nls, parms)
  return(out[,2])
}
```

I can generate a solution for a given period and damping factor, as for example here a period of 20 and a slight damping of 0.2:

```r
# small example:
time <- 1:100
period <- 20 # period of oscillation
amort_factor <- 0.2
omega <- 2*pi/period # agular frequency
oscil <- solution_analy_ODE2(omega^2,amort_factor*2*omega,time,1,0,0)
plot(time,oscil)
```

[image]

Now I generate a panel of 10 individuals with a random starting phase (i.e. different starting position and velocity). The goal is to perform a non linear regression with **random effect on the starting values**

```
library(data.table)
# generate panel
Npoint <- 100 # number of time poitns
Nindiv <- 10 # number of individuals
period <- 20 # period of oscillation
amort_factor <- 0.2
omega <- 2*pi/period # agular frequency
# random phase
phase <- sample(seq(0,2*pi,0.01),Nindiv)
# simu data:
data_simu <- data.table(time = rep(1:Npoint,Nindiv), ID = rep(1:Nindiv,each = Npoint))

# signal generation
data_simu[,signal := solution_analy_ODE2(omega2 = omega^2,
                                         esp2omega = 2*0.2*omega,
                                         time = time,
                                         y0 = sin(phase[.GRP]),
                                         v0 = omega*cos(phase[.GRP]),
                                         yeq = 0)+ 
            rnorm(.N,0,0.02),by = ID]
```

If we have a look, we have a proper dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_simu,aes(time,signal,color = ID))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~ID)
```

[image]

## The problems

### Using nlme

Using `nlme` with similar syntax working on simpler examples (non linear functions not using deSolve), I tried:

```
fit <- nlme(model = signal ~ solution_analy_ODE2(esp2omega,omega2,time,y0,v0,yeq), 
     data = data_simu,
     fixed = esp2omega + omega2 + y0 + v0 + yeq ~ 1,
     random = y0 ~ 1 ,
     groups = ~ ID, 
     start = c(esp2omega = 0.08, 
               omega2 = 0.04,
               yeq = 0,
               y0 = 1,
               v0 = 0))
```

I obtain:

> Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : The number of derivatives returned by func() (2) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (2000)

The traceback:

```
12. stop(paste("The number of derivatives returned by func() (", length(tmp[[1]]), ") must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (", length(y), ")", sep = ""))
11. checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho)
10. lsoda(xstart, time, ODE2_nls, parms)
9. solution_analy_ODE2(omega2, esp2omega, time, y0, v0, yeq)
.
.
```

I looks like `nlme` is trying to pass a vector of starting condition to `solution_analy_ODE2`, and causes an error in `checkFunc` from `lasoda`.

I tried using `nlsList`:

```
test <- nlsList(model = signal ~ solution_analy_ODE2(omega2,esp2omega,time,y0,v0,yeq) | ID, 
        data = data_simu, 
        start = list(esp2omega = 0.08, omega2 = 0.04,yeq = 0,
                     y0 = 1,v0 = 0),
        control = list(maxiter=150, warnOnly=T,minFactor = 1e-10), 
        na.action = na.fail, pool = TRUE)
head(test)
```

```
Call:
  Model: signal ~ solution_analy_ODE2(omega2, esp2omega, time, y0, v0, yeq) | ID 
   Data: data_simu 

Coefficients:
   esp2omega     omega2           yeq         y0          v0
1  0.1190764 0.09696076  0.0007577956 -0.1049423  0.30234654
2  0.1238936 0.09827158 -0.0003463023  0.9837386  0.04773775
3  0.1280399 0.09853310 -0.0004908579  0.6051663  0.25216134
4  0.1254053 0.09917855  0.0001922963 -0.5484005 -0.25972829
5  0.1249473 0.09884761  0.0017730823  0.7041049  0.22066652
6  0.1275408 0.09966155 -0.0017522320  0.8349450  0.17596648
```

We can see that te non linear fit works well on individual signals. Now if I want to perform a regression of the dataset with random effects, the syntax should be:

```
fit <- nlme(test, 
     random = y0 ~ 1 ,
     groups = ~ ID, 
     start = c(esp2omega = 0.08, 
               omega2 = 0.04,
               yeq = 0,
               y0 = 1,
               v0 = 0))
```

But I obtain the exact same error message.

I then tried using `nlmODE`, following Bne Bolker's comment on [a similar question I asked some years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254840/fitting-first-order-equation-with-nlme-and-lsoda)

### using nlmODE

```
library(nlmeODE)
datas_grouped <- groupedData( signal ~ time | ID, data = data_simu, 
                              labels = list (x = "time", y = "signal"), 
                              units = list(x ="arbitrary", y = "arbitrary"))

modelODE <- list( DiffEq = list(dS2dt = ~ S1,
                                dS1dt = ~ -esp2omega*S1  - omega2*S2 + omega2*yeq),
                  ObsEq = list(yc = ~ S2),
                  States = c("S1","S2"),
                  Parms = c("esp2omega","omega2","yeq","ID"), 
                  Init = c(y0 = 0,v0 = 0))

resnlmeode = nlmeODE(modelODE, datas_grouped) 
assign("resnlmeode", resnlmeode, envir = .GlobalEnv)
#Fitting with nlme the resulting function
model <- nlme(signal ~ resnlmeode(esp2omega,omega2,yeq,time,ID), 
              data = datas_grouped, 
              fixed = esp2omega + omega2 + yeq + y0 + v0  ~ 1, 
              random = y0 + v0 ~1,
              start = c(esp2omega = 0.08, 
                        omega2 = 0.04,
                        yeq = 0,
                        y0 = 0,
                        v0 = 0)) #
```

I get the error:

> Error in resnlmeode(esp2omega, omega2, yeq, time, ID) : object 'yhat' not found

Here I don't understand where the error comes from, nor how to solve it.

## Questions

- Can you reproduce the problem ?
- Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem, using either `nlme` or `nlmODE` ?
- If not, is there a solution using an other package ? I saw `nlmixr` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlmixr/index.html), but I don't know it, the instalation is complicated and it was recently remove from CRAN

---

## Edits

@tpetzoldt suggested a nice way to debug `nlme` behavior, and it surprised me a lot. Here is a working example with a non linear function, where I generate a set of 5 individual with a random parameter varying between individuals :

```
reg_fun = function(time,b,A,y0){
  cat("time : ",length(time)," b :",length(b)," A : ",length(A)," y0: ",length(y0),"\n")
  out <- A*exp(-b*time)+(y0-1)
  cat("out : ",length(out),"\n")
  tmp <- cbind(b,A,y0,time,out)
  cat(apply(tmp,1,function(x) paste(paste(x,collapse = " "),"\n")),"\n")
  return(out)
}

time <- 0:10*10
ramdom_y0 <- sample(seq(0,1,0.01),10)
Nid <- 5
data_simu <- 
data.table(time = rep(time,Nid),
           ID = rep(LETTERS[1:Nid],each = length(time)) )[,signal := reg_fun(time,0.02,2,ramdom_y0[.GRP]) + rnorm(.N,0,0.1),by = ID]
```

The cats in the function give here:

```
time :  11  b : 1  A :  1  y0:  1 
out :  11 
0.02 2 0.64 0 1.64 
 0.02 2 0.64 10 1.27746150615596 
 0.02 2 0.64 20 0.980640092071279 
 0.02 2 0.64 30 0.737623272188053 
 0.02 2 0.64 40 0.538657928234443 
 0.02 2 0.64 50 0.375758882342885 
 0.02 2 0.64 60 0.242388423824404 
 0.02 2 0.64 70 0.133193927883213 
 0.02 2 0.64 80 0.0437930359893108 
 0.02 2 0.64 90 -0.0294022235568269 
 0.02 2 0.64 100 -0.0893294335267746
.
.
.
```

Now I do with `nlme`:

```
nlme(model = signal ~ reg_fun(time,b,A,y0), 
     data = data_simu,
     fixed = b + A + y0 ~ 1,
     random = y0 ~ 1 ,
     groups = ~ ID, 
     start = c(b = 0.03, A = 1,y0 = 0))
```

I get:

```
time :  55  b : 55  A :  55  y0:  55 
out :  55 
0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
 0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
 0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
 0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
 0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
 
time :  55  b : 55  A :  55  y0:  55 
out :  55 
0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
 0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
 0.03 1 0 0 0 
 0.03 1 0 10 -0.259181779318282 
 0.03 1 0 20 -0.451188363905974 
 0.03 1 0 30 -0.593430340259401 
 0.03 1 0 40 -0.698805788087798 
 0.03 1 0 50 -0.77686983985157 
 0.03 1 0 60 -0.834701111778413 
 0.03 1 0 70 -0.877543571747018 
 0.03 1 0 80 -0.909282046710588 
 0.03 1 0 90 -0.93279448726025 
 0.03 1 0 100 -0.950212931632136 
...
```

So `nlme` binds 5 time (the number of individual) the time vector and pass it to the function, with the parameters repeated the same number of time. Which is of course not compatible with the way `lsoda` and my function works.

Comment: I am not sure if `with` is the reason, but it is very easy to get rid of it. Just access state variables and parameters directly, e.g. `S1 <- x[1]` or `S1 <- x["S1"]`, and the same then with `parms`. The code is then a little bit less readable, that's why most of the docs and many people prefer the `with(as.list())` construction.

Comment: I tried, and indeed it did not solve the problem. The rror message is different though, see my edits

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the ode model is called with a wrong argument, so that it gets a vector with 2000 state variables instead of 2. Try the following to see the problem:

```
ODE2_nls <- function(t, y, parms) {
  cat(length(y),"\n") # <----
  S1 <- y[1]
  dS1 <- y[2]
  dS2 <- dS1
  dS1 <- - parms["esp2omega"]*dS1  - parms["omega2"]*S1 + parms["omega2"]*parms["yeq"]
  res <- c(dS2,dS1)
  list(res)
}
```

**Edit**: I think that the analytical function worked, because it is vectorized, so you may try to vectorize the ode function, either by iterating over the ode model or (better) internally using vectors as state variables. As `ode` is fast in solving systems with several 100k equations, 2000 should be feasible.

I guess that both, states and parameters from `nlme` are passed as vectors. The state variable of the ode model is then a "long" vector, the parameters can be implemented as a list.

Here an example (edited, now with parameters as list):

```
ODE2_nls <- function(t, y, parms) {
  #cat(length(y),"\n")
  #cat(length(parms$omega2))
  ndx <- seq(1, 2*N-1, 2)
  S1  <- y[ndx]
  dS1 <- y[ndx + 1]
  dS2 <- dS1
  dS1 <- - parms$esp2omega * dS1  - parms$omega2 * S1 + parms$omega2 * parms$yeq
  res <- c(dS2, dS1)
  list(res)
}

solution_analy_ODE2 = function(omega2, esp2omega, time, y0, v0, yeq){
  parms  <- list(esp2omega = esp2omega, omega2 = omega2, yeq = yeq)
  xstart = c(S1 =  y0, dS1 = v0)
  out <-  ode(xstart, time, ODE2_nls, parms, atol=1e-4, rtol=1e-4, method="ode45")
  return(out[,2])
}
```

Then set (or calculate) the number of equations, e.g. `N <- 1` resp. `N <-1000` before the calls.

The model runs through this way, before running in numerical issues, but that's another story ...

You may then try to use another ode solver (e.g. `vode`), set `atol`and `rtol` to lower values, tweak `nmle`'s optimization parameters, use box constraints ... and so on, as usual in nonlinear optimization.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I get `2000` here, while in my first example `oscil <- solution_analy_ODE2(omega^2,amort_factor*2*omega,time,1,0,0)` I get one hundred `2` (100 being the length of `time`). But I don't understand why

Comment: I think you are right, and I understand the idea of vectorizing over `y0` and `v0` in my `solution_analy_ODE2` function. But what should be the output ? a list of vector ? a data.frame ? A concantenated vector ? What does `nlme` use ?

Comment: A vector of the appropriate structure, see example above.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way, see my edits. The problem is how `nlme` works and what it passes to the function

Comment: I edited my suggestion again, where parameters are now passed as a list instead of a vector. Parameters are passed transparently down to the model and can be any data type, while the states are directly handled by the solver and must always be a vector.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't manage to make your solution work with my example. My goal is to perform the `nlme` regression on my example dataset. I tried your function with `N <- 1000` ro `N <- 2000` and it does not work

Comment: Hi, I think we should find another place to discuss this. You find my email address in the deSolve package.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution hacking `nlme` behavior: as shown in my edit, the problem comes from the fact that `nlme` passes a vector of NindividualxNpoints to the nonlinear function,  supposing that the function associates for each time point a value. But `lsoda` don't do that, as it integrates an equation along time (i.e. it need all time until a given time poit to produce a value).

My solution consists in decomposing the parameters that `nlme` passes to my function, make the calculation, and re-create a vector:

```
detect_id <- function(vec){
  tmp <- c(0,diff(vec))
  out <- tmp
  out <- NA
  out[tmp < 0] <- 1:sum(tmp < 0)
  out <- na.locf(out,na.rm = F)
  rleid(out)
}
```

`detect_id`  decompose the time vector into single time vectors identificator:

```
detect_id(rep(1:10,3))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

And then, the function doing the numeric integration loop over each individuals, and bind the resulting vectors together:

```
solution_analy_ODE2_modif = function(omega2,esp2omega,time,y0,v0,yeq){
  tmp <- detect_id(time)
  
  out <- lapply(unique(tmp),function(i){
    idxs <- which(tmp == i)
    parms  <- c(esp2omega = esp2omega[idxs][1],
                omega2 = omega2[idxs][1],
                yeq = yeq[idxs][1])
    
    xstart = c(S1 =  y0[idxs][1], dS1 = v0[idxs][1])
    out_tmp <-  lsoda(xstart, time[idxs], ODE2_nls, parms)
    out_tmp[,2]
  }) %>% unlist()
  
  return(out)
}
```

It I make a test, where I pass a vector similar to whats `nlme` passes to the function:

```
omega2vec <- rep(0.1,30)
eps2omegavec <- rep(0.1,30)
timevec <- rep(1:10,3)
y0vec <- rep(1,30)
v0vec <- rep(0,30)
yeqvec = rep(0,30)
solution_analy_ODE2_modif(omega2 = omega2vec,
                          esp2omega = eps2omegavec,
                          time = timevec,
                          y0 = y0vec,
                          v0 = v0vec,
                          yeq = yeqvec)
 [1]  1.0000000  0.9520263  0.8187691  0.6209244  0.3833110  0.1321355 -0.1076071 -0.3143798
 [9] -0.4718058 -0.5697255  1.0000000  0.9520263  0.8187691  0.6209244  0.3833110  0.1321355
[17] -0.1076071 -0.3143798 -0.4718058 -0.5697255  1.0000000  0.9520263  0.8187691  0.6209244
[25]  0.3833110  0.1321355 -0.1076071 -0.3143798 -0.4718058 -0.5697255
```

It works. It would not work with @tpetzoldt method, because the time vector passes from 10 to 0, which would cause integration problems. Here I really need to hack the way `nlnme` works.
Now :

```
fit <- nlme(model = signal ~ solution_analy_ODE2_modif (esp2omega,omega2,time,y0,v0,yeq), 
     data = data_simu,
     fixed = esp2omega + omega2 + y0 + v0 + yeq ~ 1,
     random = y0 ~ 1 ,
     groups = ~ ID, 
     start = c(esp2omega = 0.5, 
     omega2 = 0.5,
     yeq = 0,
     y0 = 1,
     v0 = 1))
```

works like a charm

```
summary(fit)


Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: signal ~ solution_analy_ODE2_modif(omega2, esp2omega, time, y0,      v0, yeq) 
 Data: data_simu 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -597.4215 -567.7366 307.7107

Random effects:
 Formula: list(y0 ~ 1, v0 ~ 1)
 Level: ID
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
         StdDev     Corr  
y0       0.61713329 y0    
v0       0.67815548 -0.269
Residual 0.03859165       

Fixed effects: esp2omega + omega2 + y0 + v0 + yeq ~ 1 
              Value  Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
esp2omega 0.4113068 0.00866821 186  47.45002  0.0000
omega2    1.0916444 0.00923958 186 118.14876  0.0000
y0        0.3848382 0.19788896 186   1.94472  0.0533
v0        0.1892775 0.21762610 186   0.86974  0.3856
yeq       0.0000146 0.00283328 186   0.00515  0.9959
 Correlation: 
       esp2mg omega2 y0     v0    
omega2  0.224                     
y0      0.011 -0.008              
v0      0.005  0.030 -0.269       
yeq    -0.091 -0.046  0.009 -0.009

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-3.2692477 -0.6122453  0.1149902  0.6460419  3.2890201 

Number of Observations: 200
Number of Groups: 10
```

Comment: Thank you, this sounds really great! I made some more trials and saw that there was something wrong with `time` but was not able to find the reason.  One wish: can you please post a complete and reproducible solution? This would make it easier to reproduce for people (including me) who are also interested in this.